# AVSpeechSynthesizer High Quality Voices

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

Is it possible to use the enhanced/high quality voices (Alex in the U.S.) with the speech synthesizer?  I have downloaded the voices but find no way to tell the synthesizer to use it rather than the default voice.

Since voices are generally selected by BCP-47 codes and there is only on for US English, it appears there is no way to further differentiate voices. Am I missing something?  (One would think Apple might have considered a need for different dialects, but I am not seeing it).

TIA.

Comment: Having the same issue and it appears to me that it is currently simply broken, as this should work. It should automatically use the enhanced voice if available, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, possible to pick from the 2 that seem to be available on my system, like  this:

```
class Speak {

    let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
    let voiceSynth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    var voiceToUse: AVSpeechSynthesisVoice?

  init(){
    for voice in voices {
      if voice.name == "Samantha (Enhanced)"  && voice.quality == .enhanced {
        voiceToUse = voice
      }
    }    
  }

    func sayThis(_ phrase: String){
      let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: phrase)
          utterance.voice = voiceToUse
          utterance.rate = 0.5

        voiceSynth.speak(utterance) 
    }
}
```

Then, somewhere in your app, do something like this:

```
let voice = Speak()
voice.sayThis("I'm speaking better Seppo, now!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the previous versions of iOS that the apps using the synthesiser weren't using the enhanced voices. This bug has been fixed in iOS10. iOS10 now uses the enhanced voices.